# can't create links from CSV in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I can't figure out how to create links out of CSV tables in Neo4j. I've read several parts of the manual ([match](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-match.html), [loadCSV](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html), etc), that [free book](http://neo4j.com/book-learning-neo4j/), and several tutorials I've found. None of them seems to contemplate my use case (which is weird, because I think it's a pretty simple use case). I've tried adapting the code they have in all sorts of ways, but nothing seems to work.

So, I have three CSV tables: parent companies, child companies, and parent-child pairs. I begin by loading the first two tables (and that works fine - all the properties are there, all the info is correct):

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:/C:/Users/thiago.marzagao/Desktop/CSVs/children.csv" AS node
CREATE (:Children {id: node[0], name: node[1]})

LOAD CSV FROM "file:/C:/Users/thiago.marzagao/Desktop/CSVs/parents.csv" AS node 
CREATE (:Parent {id: node[0], name: node[1]})
```

Now, here's the structure of the third table:

```
child_id,parent_id
```

Here's some of the things I've tried:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:/C:/Users/thiago.marzagao/Desktop/CSVs/link.csv" AS rels
MATCH (FROM {Parent: rels[1]}), (TO {Children: rels[0]})
CREATE (Parent)-[:OWNS]->(Children)
```

This doesn't give me an eror, but it returns zero rows.

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:/C:/Users/thiago.marzagao/Desktop/CSVs/link.csv" AS rels
MATCH (FROM {id: rels[1]}), (TO {id: rels[0]})
CREATE (Parent)-[:OWNS]->(Children)
```

This doesn't give me an error, but it just returns a bunch of pairs of empty nodes. So, it creates the links, but somehow it doesn't link the actual nodes.

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:/C:/Users/thiago.marzagao/Desktop/CSVs/link.csv" AS rels
MATCH (FROM {Parent.id: rels[1]}), (TO {Children.id: rels[0]})
CREATE (Parent)-[:OWNS]->(Children)
```

This gives me a syntax error (`Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax`)

I also tried several variations of the code blocks above, but to no avail. So, what am I doing wrong? (I'm on Neo4j 2.1.6, in case that matters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your cypher statement, you are not referencing to the same identifiers used in the *MATCH* for creating the relationship, so he will just create new empty nodes :

Look at the difference :

MATCH (**FROM** {id: rels[1]}), (**TO** {id: rels[0]})

CREATE (**Parent**)-[:OWNS]->(**Children**)

Instead it should be :

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:/C:/Users/thiago.marzagao/Desktop/CSVs/link.csv" AS rels
MATCH (Parent {id: rels[1]}), (Children {id: rels[0]})
CREATE (Parent)-[:OWNS]->(Children)
```

Comment: That did the trick. I guess I saw several examples using FROM and TO and I failed to realize these were field names and not keywords...